# parsing a short hyphen?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've never seen this before, but I was parsing a string time range I am getting back from a third party service.  The full time part of the string is: `10:30 am – 11:30 am`.  If I try and do:

```
var times = '10:30 am – 11:30 am'.split('-');
```

my result is

['10:30 am – 11:30 am']

Using the Node console, I can copy the hyphen (instead of typing the one on my keyboard) and it's still just one character, but it splits correctly.

```
var times = '10:30 am – 11:30 am'.split('–');
```

results in

```
['10:30 am ',' 11:30 am']
```

So I guess what I don't understand is what's the thing that looks like a single hyphen (minus sign) to my old eyes that's apparently different from the minus sign on my keyboard?

Comment: That's an `&ndash;` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Comment: "–".charCodeAt(0) === "-".charCodeAt(0) => false

Comment: As an alternative you could use `var times = '10:30 am – 11:30 am'.split(/\s.\s/);` in case they are not consistent with the type of dash they use.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, folks, never seen that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others already answered: it's the [**en ndash**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) character. If you suspect it within a string and want to split on it, you could use:

```
'10:30 am – 11:30 am'.split(/\-|\u2013/);
```